# Items of on boarding screens are not appearing in Collection View Cells in XCode - Designed in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard, screen

I'm making an onboarding screen for a project in which I've used storyboard for design and collection view to scroll steps of on boarding screen.
No error in the code run but collection views items are not appearing..

```
import UIKit

class OnBoardingViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var ImageCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var skipButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
    
       
    var slides: [OnBoardingSlide] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        slides = [
            OnBoardingSlide(title: "This is the Title", description: "This is the description", image: UIImage(named: "onBoarding1")!),
            OnBoardingSlide(title: "This is the Title", description: "This is the description", image: UIImage(named: "onBoarding2")!),
            OnBoardingSlide(title: "This is the Title", description: "This is the description", image: UIImage(named: "onBoarding1")!)
        ]
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    @IBAction func skipButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
}

extension OnBoardingViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return slides.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: OnBoardingCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! OnBoardingCollectionViewCell
        cell.setup(slides[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: There could be so many reasons. If app is not crashing try giving background color to your cell. I don’t see any code for layout. Try giving fixed width and height for now and see if you see anything. How you are defining layout?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please first check if you assigned a `dataSource` to the `collectionView` in `Storyboard`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in your viewDidLoad Method below the Array Declaration and your code will work.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.ImageCollectionView.delegate = self 
    self.ImageCollectionView.dataSource = self
    self.ImageCollectionView.relaodData()
 }
```

and replace collection view with Your collectionView Name like below i have changed:

```
 let cell = 
 self.ImageCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
 OnBoardingCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! 
 OnBoardingCollectionViewCell
```

sometime your delegate works faster when array is getting the values if it still not work then you have to check your constraints of cell items.

Comment: can you please share your storyboard layout, the issue must be due to any reason, maybe elements are not aligned correctly so they are not getting Height. or if you can share some more information to resolve the issue?